# identifying the input as local folder or s3 bucket

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services

Source could be local folder or s3 bucket. How we can make input parameter to identify entered parameter as local folder or s3 bucket?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please give more context, code, configurations files in order to help you accordingly. Also your questions it's very vague, can you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: SOURCE – could be local folder or s3_bucket/prefix...
TARGET - always s3_bucket/prefix....

To work both with 'local folder vs bucket' and 'bucket1 vs bucket2' 
 script should work with local folder as source OR with s3 bucket as source. So script should be able to accept either one as a source parameter and NOT just using local folder then s3 bucket in the same run.

Basically this bash script to accept the input parameter as local or s3 bucket and compare with other s3 bucket and output the difference result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s3 bucket is accessed using path style mentioned here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html
You should write pattern check on your input to identify if the input is s3 bucket or bucket object.

Other way, if your input for local path is always going to exists on the system, then you can run path canonicalization commands and get absolute path of the local folder. e.g. on Unix you can run realpath() system api.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html

realpath() api will resolve to actual path only when the input path exists otherwise it returns the error. You can send your input to realpath command, if it passes, it is your local path on the system.